# What is the creature that appears after beating False Knight?

Tags: hollow-knight

Immediately after beating False Knight in Steel Soul mode this thing popped up and started scurrying away slowly: [image]

What is it? I seem to be able to knock it around, but once I stop it quickly gets up again and moves off. Is there anything I can do with it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Steel Soul mode, it's always there. This is just the False Knight's mace. Apparently the False Knight stuck a little bug at the end of a metal rod to fight with, and once the Knight is defeated that bug scurries away.

You can't really do anything with it, it's just there for a bit of humour.

Comment: Of course, I should have recognized it! Poor thing being banged around like that :)

Comment: Dreamnailed, the bug's dialogue is "Free at last!"

Answer (score 0):

Its the mace false knight uses. It appears after defeating him in any gamemode and can be attacked and will roll a short distance away before getting up and running towards the nearest exit. Once it leaves the room it is not seen again.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the existing answer. Please read those before posting. Better yet, please take our [Tour]. Welcome to Arqade!